# Proving email messages have been read, and by whom

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, email

I had been requested to provide one of our user access to her GMail. Our computer policy states "no internet email" so our Sonciwall generates a message explaining that this is forbidden.

I still got requested to do this so I researched and found a solution that would permit the GMail account to be added into Outlook. I did all the research and testing of the outlined procedures on my PC using and after seeing that it all worked as described, I then did the procedure on the users PC who requested this.

Now months later a new IT director has dissected my local OST file and is levying charges on me that I was reading that persons GMail email. I have never examined an OST file and wonder if it really would provide details that proves I would have read any of the emails in the newly added GMail account that was installed into my Outlook when I was researching/testing. I think I understand the OST would have essentially snap shots from  my Outlook so I would expect that the GMail folder would have been added into my OST. But to claim this is evidence of me reading the email that got saved into this folder is beyond my belief.

Can anyone verify the OST would show what files were read and by whom?

Comment: When you say "and is levying charges on me" do you mean actual legal charges?  If so, consult a lawyer, not the internet.

Comment: Exactly what was the method you used to connect outlook to gmail?  POP3?  IMAP?  Email forwarding?  Forwarding gmail emails to a printer that prints it out, then feeds the printout into a scanner, then emails the scan to your work address?

Comment: not legal charges   just comments made about me

Comment: Grant..POP3 I believe

Answer (score 3):

The OST/PST just holds e-mails downloaded from accounts. It does not prove anything.